# Is there any way to create range from table column with random value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get a range in which a number will fall, the range will be the created from the values of a column of the table, for ex. let there be a column 'num1' which contains data (12,15,10,40,20,5) and i give 23 as number to search  then  i can get output as '20 and 40'

i can achieve the desired output by two queries but i want to have a single query,
column will have unique values so if a column value matches then the range will be the number and its nearest smaller value for ex. if input is 15 then output will be 12 and 15
Column value:(12,15,10,40,20,5) search value:30 desired output: '20 and 40'

Comment: What's the expected result for search value 15? 5? 4?

Comment: @jarlh it will be '12 and 15' for 15 and the random value for search will be in between the lowest and the highest value of the column i.e between 5 to 40 sorry i missed that

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will work in your favor. Using LEAD() AND LAG() window functions to obtain the previous and next values for a row.

[Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/02ec5/6)

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Number INT)
INSERT @T VALUES(12),(15),(10),(40),(20),(5)

SELECT 
  Number,
  NextNumber = ISNULL(LEAD(Number) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Number),Number),
  LastNumber = ISNULL(LAG(Number) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Number),Number)
FROM 
   T
```

From the buildup table you now need to match the input on acceptable ranges and pick the best match (in this case it is the closest to the range start/end).

```
DECLARE @NumberToSearch INT =23

;WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT 
        Number,
        RangeStart = ISNULL(LAG(Number) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Number) ,Number), 
        RangeEnd = ISNULL(LEAD(Number) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Number) , Number)
    FROM 
        @T
)
,ApplicableRanges AS
(
    SELECT 
        Number,
        RangeStart,
        RangeEnd,
        Instance = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY  RangeStart)
    FROM
        Ranges R
    WHERE
        @NumberToSearch BETWEEN R.RangeStart AND R.RangeEnd
)

SELECT * FROM ApplicableRanges WHERE Instance = 1
```